# SQL Generic Error When Notes are Clicked Dynamic CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am using dynamic CRM 2015 version 7.0.1.129 On-Premise. When user click on notes in social pane. An error shows up which is "Generic SQL Error".

Here is the log

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Generic SQL error.Detail:
>
> ```
> <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
>     <ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>
>     <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
>     <Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>
>     <Timestamp>2016-04-12T17:00:52.6982705Z</Timestamp>
>     <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
>     <TraceText i:nil="true" />
> </OrganizationServiceFault>
> ```

Actually the main issue is that the error is only showing for a single user not all of them and this happens every time when he click on Notes within a Pipeline Opportunity.

Any kind of Help/Suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That error could be a whole lot of things...since you're on premise you can get a trace. Use [this tool](https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/) to enable tracing. Then use [this tool](https://crmtracereader.codeplex.com/) to find the error. Don't forget to turn tracing off after you're done.

Comment: i will try your suggestion and let you know if i figure out what the problem really is

Comment: @Alessiox My links refer to tools he needs to d/l...I can't upload them to SO, can I?